# Can I have two PEX8748 downstream ports to communicate w/ each other?

Tags: pci-express

The setup is like this: One host connects to one NVMe card which uses a PEX8748 to connect the SSDs. What we want is to have two such NVMe ports connected using a cross cable (TX - RX, and vice versa), so that the two hosts can talk to each other. Is this possible?

Update per @peregrino69 's request:
The question asked is how to have two host communicate w/ each other through two EP ports. We've learnt that this seems only to be possible w/ two EP ports configured as NTB ports.
Now our new question is: What are the cheapest chips that can support NTB mode?

Comment: Sorry but the question is unclear. Do you want to use the device in lieu of a network connection to provide direct connectivity between systems, or something else? Please don't answer in comments, [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1772210/edit) your question instead to provide more context to your need.